# Recibir por teclado elemento de clase Vector java

Tags: java, vectores

Estoy realizando un programa simple para entender el funcionamiento de la clase vector, pero cuando lo ejecuto no me muestra ni me pide nada el programa. Concretamente no sé como hacer para que el usuario ingrese por teclado un numero y este se guarde como un elemento de mi clase Vector.

```
package entrenamiento.ahora.si.de.vectores.xd;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;

/**
 *
 * @author Usuario
 */
public class EntrenamientoAhoraSiDeVectoresXD {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vector  numeros = new Vector (5,5);
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        for(int i=0; i<numeros.size(); i++){
            System.out.println("Ingrese un numero para agregarlo al vector");
            numeros.addElement(i);
            
        }
        for(int i=0; i<numeros.size(); i++){
            System.out.println("Los numeros ingresados al vector son ");
            System.out.println("Elemento "+(i+1) + ": "+numeros.elementAt(i));
        }
    }
    
}
```

Esto me muestra cuando esta en ejecución

```
run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu programa hace exactamente lo que ves.. nada..

Y esto porque?? porque para entender el funcionamiento de algo, nada mejor que leer la documentacion de ese algo...

Si vamos a la [documentacion de la clase Vector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#Vector-int-int-)

Y mas precisamente al metodo que estas usando, dice:

> public Vector(int initialCapacity,
> int capacityIncrement)
> Constructs an empty vector with the specified initial capacity and capacity increment.
> Parameters:
> initialCapacity - the initial capacity of the vector
> capacityIncrement - the amount by which the capacity is increased when the vector overflows

O sea, que estas creando un Vector vacio, con capacidad de 5 elementos en un principio, y que cada vez que llegue a 5, va a aumentar la capacidad en 5 mas...

Por eso, size te devuelve cero. No tiene elementos.